# How to set Cache-control for ActiveStorage Disk service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have a simple Rails 6 app with ActiveStorage. I use local disk storage. When I inspect responses from representation url like this

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/some-long-hash/IMG_0951.jpeg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22IMG_0951.jpeg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27IMG_0951.jpeg
```

I see headers Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate

The question is how to make Rails to set public caching header with some age?

Answer (score 1):

Builinding on [@anothermh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74838388/220292), here a up-2-date version for Rails 7.1 - After Zeitwerk it is difficult to call controllers or models directly from an initializer.

```rb
# config/initializers/active_storage_cache_control.rb
  Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare do
    ActiveStorage::DiskController.class_eval do
      before_action only: [:show] do
        response.set_header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=86400, public')
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Clarification: It is unrelated to Zeitwerk. This change was necessary because accessing reloadable code from spots that run only once during boot just does not make sense. Changes in reloaded code won't have any effect there. In other words, if Zeitwerk had not been created, this change would have been added to Rails as well.

Comment: In the example above, if you define a callback in the disk controller and then reload, the reloaded controller won't have the callback in place, because the initializer would not have been executed. This error is precisely what the change prevents (an API should not make erroneous usage possible by design).

Comment: @XavierNoria Thanks for the clarification (and creating Zeitwerk). I didn't meant it was Zeitwerk's fault, but when migrating to Zeitwerk, that kind of mistake was more obvious because one would get UndefinedConstant errors during the transition to Zeitwerk when referencing Application Code's constant during init. Before Zeitwerk, that kind of code might or might not have worked until a development reload :)

Comment: Thanks :). Not really! In Rails 6.x you could still autoload from init, both in :zeitwerk and :classic modes. And you got warnings in the logs. You could migrate to Zeitwerk and carry those warnings. If you did not address the warnings, you'll find you cannot boot any more in Rails 7. The factor here is the Rails version, really.

Answer (score 0):

The [`#show`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/disk_controller.rb#L12-L20) method for `ActiveStorage::DiskController` is [difficult to override](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/feature-proposal-override-controllers-in-activestorage-configuration/79315) but it can be done.

A simpler approach is to add an [`after_action`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#other-ways-to-use-filters) callback for the existing `#show` method to insert the `Cache-Control` header when it is called:

```rb
# config/initializers/active_storage.rb

require 'active_storage/current'

ActiveStorage::Current.url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

require 'active_storage/set_current'
require 'active_storage/base_controller'
require 'active_storage/file_server'
require 'active_storage/disk_controller'

class ActiveStorage::DiskController < ActiveStorage::BaseController
  after_action do
    response.set_header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600, public') if action_name == 'show'
  end
end
```

Requesting an ActiveStorage URL then returns the custom `Cache-Control` header value in the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public
...
```